# Word index entry syntax

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

When creating an index entry via Alt+Shift+X it inserts a code line like this at the current pointer position:

```
{ XE "Main entry" \t "see there" }
```

If I click then on `Insert index` to create an index table the entry is recognised and included into the index table. However, if I simply manually write this code line it is not recognised as an index entry.

What magic is happening here?

Comment: Note that although you cannot create it directly, you CAN copy it directly, saving a lot of re-entering of the data (and avoiding differences).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press that key combination, Microsoft Word is actually creating a field. These are special structures in a Word document which add dynamic behavior to your document. You can normally tell if what you have in front of you is a field by the curly brackets.

You can also insert these fields yourself by clicking Insert -> Quick Parts -> Fields and scrolling down to the XE field.

Comment: Thank you Adam. Now it is clear. Can the above code for the field also be inserted via VBA?

Comment: Yes it can, use: ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=Selection.Range, Entry:= _
EntryText, CrossReference:="", _
CrossReferenceAutoText:="", BookmarkName:="", Bold:=False, _
Italic:=False

Comment: Thank you Adam. The code is working great!

Regards,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research.  Here's what I found along with the source:

> How to Override Word's Default Sorting There is an undocumented feature that allows you to apply manual sorting overrides for your entries. Follow the entry level that you want differently sorted with a semicolon and the sort text itself. In the example below, the main heading will appear re-alphabetized as if the text of the main heading were actually "resortedmain." The subheading is also re-alphabetized as if it were spelled "resortedsub."
>
> ```
> {XE "main;resortedmain:sub;resortedsub:sub-sub;resortedsub-sub")
> ```

I didn't try and duplicate this to see if it works.

The source is: http://taxonomist.tripod.com/indexing/wordproblems.html#override

Let me know if this works.